# .OrderBy(DayOfWeek) to treat Sunday as the end of the week

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dayofweek

I'm ordering a number of objects by their [`System.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) property.

[DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) treats Sunday as the *start* of the week, whereas I would like it to be ordered so it appears at the *end*.  It's just an enum, so I can't modify it. However I've read that I may be able to create a [custom culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but think this is probably overkill.

`List<TimeBand> orderedTimeBands = timeBands.OrderBy(x => x.DayName).ToList()`

So `DayName` is a `DayOfWeek`, i want `orderedTimeBands` to be ordered from Monday -> Sunday.

Any ideas?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Sorry if I wasn't clear, it's a `System.DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The simplest approach would be:

```
var orderedTimeBands = timeBands.OrderBy(x => ((int) x.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7)
                                .ToList()
```

So we have:

```
Name        Original value      Value after arithmetic
Sunday       0                  6
Monday       1                  0
Tuesday      2                  1
Wednesday    3                  2
Thursday     4                  3
Friday       5                  4
Saturday     6                  5
```

... which is what you want, I think.

Comment: this ( +1 ) or as pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135587/c-set-initial-dayofweek-as-monday-not-sunday you could write a "custom" CurrentCulture and simply tell there that its monday

Comment: @Najzero: Yes, the OP mentioned the custom culture idea in the question. I'd definitely consider that to be overkill.

Comment: Great example of thinking out of the box, glad you agree with me that a custom culture is overkill.  Seems to work, I'll just make sure I put it in a method that describes why we're using addition and modulus to save future confusion.

Answer (score 14):

I use a solution based on current culture:

```
// all days of week
var daysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>();

// get first day of week from current culture
var firstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

// all days of week ordered from first day of week
var daysOfWeekOrdered = daysOfWeek.OrderBy(x => (x - firstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7);
```

The important part is the `OrderBy` lambda. It's basically a **parametrized version of [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591070/108374) above**.

This way it will be ordered from Monday in the UK, and from Sunday in the US.