# .net get Days of week and Sort by Start day

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I am getting Abbreviated Day Names by culture an insert into a Class model:

```
        var daysNames = new CultureInfo(culture).DateTimeFormat
            .AbbreviatedDayNames
            .Select((item) => new CalendarDaysItem(item.ToUppercaseFirst()))
            .ToList();
```

[image]

But i need Sort the List with a specific Week Day, i Try this sample:

```
        var firstDayOfWeek = new CultureInfo(culture).DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

        var daysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
            .Cast<DayOfWeek>()
            .OrderBy(x => (x - firstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7);

        var daysOfWeekOrdered = daysOfWeek.OrderBy(x => (x - firstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7);
```

[image]

But the culture is EN-US and i need to change by parameter

Comment: Can you add sample input and output data? I don't understand `Sort the List with a specific Week Day`

Comment: Do you want to change the culture?

Comment: Yes i need change de culture

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, you current implementation sorts the days using the day of the week of the culture you supplied. Is this not what you want?

Comment: In second image i need the text be in "pt-PT",

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve your issue. Please try with the below code:

var dateTimes = timeBands.OrderBy(x => ((int) x.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7)
                                .ToList()

For more info you can refer this : [.OrderBy(DayOfWeek) to treat Sunday as the end of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591039/orderbydayofweek-to-treat-sunday-as-the-end-of-the-week)

Answer (score 1):

```
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
            DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            var daysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
               .Cast<DayOfWeek>()
               .OrderBy(x => (x - firstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)
               .Select(x => DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedDayName(x))
               .ToList();
```